# How to I update state when props are set using mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I set the `defaultValue` of a text field using props set by Redux’s `mapStateToProps`.

When the text field changes (detected using `onChange={...}`), I call `setState` to capture user input.

Problem is, currently, if the text field doesn’t change, `setState` is never called. If a user submits the form, the `defaultValue` doesn’t make it to state so an empty string is submitted.

Many recommend using `componentWillReceiveProps` but this method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Provide value to the component's state either via  [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) for the class component or via calling `setState` from the `useEffect` callback for the functional component:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(props.propFromRedux)
useEffect(() => setState(props.propFromRedux), [props.propFromRedux])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jeggettx. Problem is `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called on each `onChange` event which resets the state to the value from Redux. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: Solved the above issue by checking is state property is defined... isn’t there a more efficient way of doing this as `getDerivedStateFromProps` is fired on each `onChange` event? New to React... feels like a Redux hook of sorts would be a more efficient way of handling this.

Comment: can you attach your code? 

there is few ways to make that, and the easiest way depends on how your code looks right now.

making handle submit do something only if e.target.value > 0 / add at the action this condition etc ...